# Iframe Yoututbe Fullscreen on Ionic framework

Tags: android, iphone, iframe, mobile, ionic-framework

Hello I would like to ask if there is a way I can do to automatically fullscreen a Youtube video on an Iframe upon changing the screen orientation on landscape and exit to full screen on portrait. I'm using ionic framework 1.1.0 (xenon xerus).

Comment: try with this plugin https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

Comment: what should i do to trigger Iframe's full screen